# How to trigger a lightbox from inside a SWF?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, actionscript, lightbox

I am using the magnific-popup (http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/) but I don't need to use this one. I have just used it before and it worked well.

My questions is how to actually trigger different lightboxes from inside a SWF?

We have one SWF that has images and animation located at six different sections of the screen. It's sort of a launch page and each section has an image with some animation and when the users clicks on a section another web page will load.

This application will be hosted on a computer with a touch screen and we were using a kiosk app to run the app and it had a small navigation bar built in but now we are using a different operating system that works better with the touch screen hardware (OSX to Windows 8) but does not work with the same kiosk app. I also can't seem to find any kiosk apps that do the same thing for Windows 8.

Instead of using a Kiosk app I would like to just use Chrome in Kiosk/Fullscreen mode and have each section open in a new lightbox window instead of using a navigation bar. However, I can't seem to trigger the lightbox event from within the SWF itself.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: in as2 something like this getURL("javascript: lightbox(maybe-attributes);"); or using flash.external.ExternalInterface class. I don't know in as3 if there's another class/method.

Comment: Thanks keypaul. After reading your comment and looking for ExternalInterface Class I was able to find this which is exactly what I am trying to do.

http://grasshopperpebbles.com/jquery/actionscript-using-lightbox-with-flash/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In as2 something like this getURL("javascript: lightbox(maybe-attributes);"); or using flash.external.ExternalInterface class. I don't know in as3 if there's another class/method

Christian find perfect match with this jquery/flash.external.ExternalInterface
http://grasshopperpebbles.com/jquery/actionscript-using-lightbox-with-flash/